# PHP Exec bash script to restart screen session

Tags: php, python, bash, exec, gnu-screen

So, I wanted to create a sort of a webadmin panel to restart an IRC bot running in Python.
I have a Bash script that succesfully restarts the bot through the terminal but, when using it with exec on a PHP page it only stops it but doesn't start it again.

Here's the bash script:

```
screen -S bot -p 0 -X quit
screen -S bot -fa -d -m -L python botpy/Run.py
```

and here's the php code:

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   exec('sudo /root/bot.sh');
?>
```

I've created all the exceptions in the sudoers file, which seems to have had effect since it stops the bot itself through the php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a click on my head, I tried to change the path to the Python script on the bash script and voilá, just added /root/ and it's working now.